# Any limitations with svn and c# / visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, svn, version-control, smartsvn

In other languages such as objective c there are certain files that you can't (or shouldn't) put under version control such as the story board and user data.

Does C# and Visual Studio suffer with any of these limitations?

edit: We are using Smart SVN.

edit2: from your comments it sounds like these would be the optimal global ignores: *.suo *.user *.ncb *.aps bin obj Debug Release temp debug release

Comment: It depends what source control software you choose to use.

Comment: Visual Studio hasn't a built in client for svn (subversion). There is a commercial one. However do you need to know which files shouldn't be versioned?

Comment: Do you dynamic local files such .user and .suo files? You shouldn't add these when your using svn?

Comment: @Jeff - We are using Smart SVN

Comment: @Gabe - I'm interested in both "can't" and "shouldn't".

Comment: @Adrian Iftod - Things that can't be put under version control or any other limitations that anyone thinks of.   Even things like xcode giving you a warning when your code doesn't match whats in the repository.

Comment: @Mytheral Edit2: Updated my answer, short: yes. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At our company we're working with VS2010 and Subversion too. So far we never had any problems. We're using [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) and [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) as clients.
We only added some files to the ignore list, mainly *.user and *.suo. Those files save local paths which are only interesting for local users. No need to have them in the repository. It's no problem if you commit them, it's just not necessary (at least from my personal experience, it might save some trouble not adding them to version control).

Edit to your edit: Yes, those files/folders can be ignored. Basically anything that is created at the client side when it is needed. Also this way users can have their own settings and work environment without colliding with other users path layout, for example.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a *MS-SCCI* Subversion plug-in like [Agent SVN](http://www.zeusedit.com/agent/) then the Visual Studio IDE itself will control what files get added to the repository.

Answer (score 2):

We have been using visual studio in combination with Visual SVN (commercial use) for over a year now and the only issue we had was that some files from the project templates had multiple line endings which caused the commit to fail. Only after we fixed the line endings we could commit those files.

Another limitation in the current version we use is that committing a solution with externals in it does not go as smooth as it should. Externals not being committed and/or marked as no changes (while they in fact where changed).

A workaround is using TortoiseSVN which is being used in Windows explorer and not in Visual Studio itself. Never had any problems using this program

Comment: There's also AnkhSVN (http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) which integrates as a source control provider for VS and use TortoiseSVN for some other more significant operations outside of VS.  In my experience, I haven't had any significant issues with any of the SVN providers (VisualSVN, AnkhSVN, TortoiseSVN).